# How to remove digits that comes inside parentheses using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let say '**Ben-Hur (2016)**'. I want to remove '**(2016)**'.I need only **Ben-Hur**.

Comment: Hint: You can use RegEx with `String.replace()`

Comment: thanks alot. One more thing. how to remove out side of (**2016**). means i want to keep '**(2016)**' and want to remove **Ben-Hur**. how to do this??

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method

```js
console.log(
  'Ben-Hur (2016)'.replace(/\(\d+\)/g, '')
)
```

**FYI :** If you want to remove the space then use `/\s*\(\d+\)\s*/g` regex.

Comment: I'll also remove trailing spaces.

Comment: @Tushar : little confused that he needs or not.... updated...